# Cannot install python module urlparse

Tags: python, package-management, pip

some program written in Python 2.7 complains that `ImportError: No module named 'urlparse'`. So I need to install the module, but I am not able to do it. The module does exist, it is described e.g. at https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html. However, neither `apt-get install`, nor `pip install` are able to find a module named `urlparse`, `python-urlparse`, `urllib`, `python-urllib`... -- I'm getting messages like  `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement ...` The only exception is the package `python-urllib3` which probably contains the needed files but for Python 3 and installation of which did not help.

I've installed `pip`, not `pip3` since I need the module for Python 2 (`pip 1.4.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`). My Ubuntu is Xubuntu 13.10.

Where's the problem, please? Is `pip` searching for the module in the right places? I don't know what locations it should search in...

Comment: check out output of `pip search urlparse`

Comment: `urlparse` is part of the standard library, i.e. it is automatically installed together with Python itself. You won't be able to install il through apt, pip or easy_install.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is out of date.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`urlparse` is part of the standard Python 2 library. It's shipped as part of Python; it isn't packaged separately on PyPI et al. `urlparse.urlparse` (the function) was renamed in Python 3 to `urllib.parse`.

So, a few things to look at:

- Your Python 2 program might be running under Python 3. Check the launch script to see how it picks which version of Python. It should probably start `#!/usr/bin/env python2` but also double check (by running `env python2`) that that loads up Python 2.
- Something has eaten `/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py`, in which case reinstall the `libpython2.7-stdlib` package with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython2.7-stdlib
  ```
- Or you have a local file causing mischief...

Answer (score 14):

If you need to write code which is Python2 and Python3 compatible you can use the following import

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python 2 install it using

```
pip install urlparse2
```